# Android Studio: jump to definition (cmd+click) from android code to kotlin/native code goes to decompiled .class instead of .kt

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-native

I have a project for android that uses an own library with kotlin/native to share it with iOS app. I started it with this [tutorial](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/01_Introduction).

It's working perfectly, already on production, so I'm very happy with it but I have one problem that I'm not able to solve:
In Android Studio, when I cmd+click a kotlin/native function from the android project class (also kotlin) it goes to decompiled .class file instead of the .kt file. This make it much slower to debug or just implement new functions.

I tried to add `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` to settings.gradle but it doesn't help.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing some configuration property but I'm not able to find it out.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230781/kotlin-multiplatform-go-to-declaration-goes-to-decompiled-code

Comment: @Patrick my question has been made before, so yours is the duplicated ;) but thanks, I will check your question in case it has any good feedback.

Comment: yes, we can close one once it has answer.  Wanted to link to the bug report.