# Kotlin multiplatform 'Go to declaration' goes to decompiled code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

When using using Android Studio's 'Go to declaration' feature (cmd + click), a decompiled source is shown, when though the source is in my project.  The kotlin MP source is in another module.  I can connect the source using the 'choose sources...' option, however I have to do this for each file.  Is there a global fix for connecting to the correct source files?

Comment: looks like this was already asked, no answers yet - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729337/android-studio-jump-to-definition-cmdclick-from-android-code-to-kotlin-nativ

Comment: From the number of up votes without a solution I'm guessing this is a bug.  I've opened an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38309?project=kt

Comment: Hello, @Patrick! I was revisiting popular yet unanswered questions about kotlin-multiplatform, and found that your YouTrack issue was closed as "Incomplete". Can you please comment a little - did you fix the issue somehow, or is the problem still relevant? For the latter, consider extending the report with information about its reproduce. Project example, version and environment details, etc.